# symfony2 class and repos architetture

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm building an application in symfony2 just to better understand how it works. My problem is I'm undecided on where to put some classes, for example:
I have a category entity and a category repository, and a controller to manage categories where I query the repos (how explained in the cookbook) using

```
$category = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository()
```

now I'm working on a blog controller, I want to display a form (for example in edit mode), so I have to query the blog repos, but I also need to query again the category repos to permit to choose a category.

I don't think it could be a good idea to query 2 different repos in the controller, can anyone suggest me how to organize this classes just to avoid to instantiate all the repository in all the actions I need them?
any other useful suggestion on how to organize the code?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with calling methods of 2 (or more) repositories in a single controller.

But in the scenario you describe the Form Component will take case of querying for categories to choose from. I suggest you dive a litter deeper in that [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html). Hint: the [Entity Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) .

**Some advice**

You probably know what "[spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)" is, but there's also something called "[lasagna code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code#Lasagna_code)" which is the opposite: you get pillars of classes that don't really work together.

You could have a pillar for users (UserEntity, UserRepository, UserService and UserController) and another for blog-posts (BlogPostEntity, BlogPostRepository, BlogPostService and BlogPostController), etc...

This is also something you rather not create, so a good mix between spaghetti and lasagna would be advisable ;)

Try to have services represent your business needs / the business world (or [Domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design#Core_definitions)). Controllers are nothing more than connectors between clients (browsers, etc) and your services. And repositories are just technical details (not your points of focus).

**PS: Little correction**

You should change this:

```
$category = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository();
```

to this:

```
$categoryRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Category');
```

It will be less confusing for you in the long run. Example:

```
$categoryRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Category');
$category = $categoryRepository->find(123);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had a look to entity field type and I think I will use it like the example you show me. 
In order to make reusable the entity filed I'm going to create, can I create a class for each of them and where the best place to put them? Can I use them from a controller?
thanks

Comment: If you're going to use the Entity Field Type for the `category` property, it's an existing type, so already reusable. If you're talking about the entire form for the blogpost, then yes, create [form class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes) for that! Place it in the `/Form/Type` folder in your bundle (something like `src/Acme/BlogBundle/Form/Type/BlogPostType.php`).